# Can a photon be captured in a grid space representation at a fractional Planck position?

Tags: particle-physics, spacetime, distance

Consider a photon, positioned in space in a finite portion of a grid. Any point of the grid is vertically or horizontally aligned, each distanced by a Planck unit.

$l_P = 1.616 199(97) × 10−35 m$

The speed of the photon is, in this grid, $v = l_P/t_P$

The photon is first captured at its original point $A$, when $t = 0*t_P$ and $x_A = 5*l_P$.

It is then captured at point $B$, when $t = 10*t_P$. Logically, the position of point B is $x_B = x_A + 10*l_P = 15*l_P$, and $y_B = y_A$.

This is a two-dimensional representation of the aforementioned grid:

[image]

The problem here is the actual definition of the Planck distance unit. By definition, a Planck distance can only have a natural coefficient, which means that the unit cannot have a fractional-represented coefficient with it.

Mathematically, it is possible to divide any unit in half. However, the Planck time unit is calculated using the Planck distance unit as well, which means it cannot be fractional as well.

Since the definition of Planck units describes how they cannot be fractionally split, the photon is *never* going through the $3.5 * l_P$ mark during its movement. Does that mean that we can define time as a frame cycle, where the fastest frame rate is $1*t_P$, and that the photon basically *changes position* to the closest Planck distance grid point (without having a transitional point in space and time during the process)? In other words, does the photon even reach point $C$ during the translation from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: Spacetime quantization doesn't work like a grid. Consider the much more simple problem of quantization of angular momentum. How does it work there?

Comment: it is conjectured both that there is no detectable 3d grid, and that there is (contrarian/ minority/ near radical pov), and there are some recent serious cutting edge experiments to try to discriminate the two cases using very sensitive detection. the latter case has been called "evidence for living in a simulation"... see eg [simulation](https://vzn1.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/on-the-so-called-loophole-free-bell-entanglement-test-and-other-hot-developments-in-qm-theory-applications/#e) for misc refs

Comment: @vzn: Absolutely nobody of any importance in physics thinks of the universe as some kind of simulation and they for sure would not think of it as a trivial grid simulation, even if they did. All of that is pseudo-science fringe.

Comment: _ok! the establishment hath spoken!_ except... [wheelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Archibald_Wheeler) [it from bit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Archibald_Wheeler#It_from_bit) has shades of [digital physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics). ['t hooft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerard_%27t_Hooft) ***nobel prize physicist*** proposes cellular automata models last few years. _etc!_ are these two (and many others) "nobodies of any importance"? oh yeah, and theres also _[bohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicate_and_explicate_order)_ =O